# uwsgi + flask + python print stop working after request.get()

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, uwsgi

I have an issue when trying to log python prints using uwsgi from the console.

So I run my application from the console with:

```
uwsgi --http :9090 --wsgi-file wsgi.py --master -p 4
```

My wsgy.py file contains:

```
from assets_generator import app as application

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

and my app looks like this (inside asset_generator.py):

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.from_envvar('CONFIG')

from uwsgidecorators import thread
from worker import Worker

@thread
def _start_worker(item):
    worker = Worker(item=item)
    worker.run()

@app.route("/post-asset", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def post_asset():
    from flask import request
    _start_worker(request.values)
    return "OK", 200
```

The worker's run class calls a convert method:

```
class Worker(object):
    def __init__(self, item):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.item = item

    def run(self):
        with app.app_context():
            # prepare stuff for convertion, fill urls etc....
            details = self.convert(
                name=self.item.get('name'),
                source_url=self.item.get('source_url'),
                conversion_format=self.item.get('format'),
                default_options=default_options
            )
```

and the convert methods calls an url:

```
def convert(self, name, source_url, conversion_format, default_options):

try:
    print "before requests " + source_url # THIS PRINT WORKS
    r = requests.get(source_url)  
    print "after requests"                # THIS ONE DOESN'T

    # do other stuff, prints doesn't work

except Exception as e:
   print " Error"
   raise e
finally:
   print "finally"                        # DOESN'T PRINT
   if zip_extract_path:
      shutil.rmtree(zip_extract_path)

print "before returning None"             # DOESN'T PRINT
return None
```

My problem is that I can see the first print in the uwsgi console logs, but the second one actually never happen, and any other prints that are after this request call never happen.

I have tested manually to do the

```
r = requests.get(source_url)
```

with the right url from the place where this uwsgi applicaiton is ran, and the requests actually succeed and return OK.

I am a bit confused why my prints stop working, If anyone has an insight on this, it would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: where is the loop that is supposed to trigger the GET request over and over again ?

Comment: Hello, there is no such loop, the convert method is called only once, then stuff is done with the r.content form the r = requests.get(source_url), and basically nothing is ever printed after this call to requests.get(source_url)

Comment: that is my point - why are you expecting more than a single print if you only trigger it once ?

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I have updated the last example to reflect what I mean by: other prints are not displayed. For example I should see a "finally" string printed in the console, and I don't, same for "before returning None", it is never shown.

Comment: aha I understand the problem now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, after trying to print a non-existing variable, and setting `--py-autoreload 1` in the uwsgi config, my logs are now displayed, I don't understand why though.

Answer (score 0):

you should pass flush=True to print statement for ex.

```
print("Hello", flush=True)
```

or use`import sys
sys.stdout.flush()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried that (sys.stdout.flush()), but it doesn't change anything, first print statement is displayed, but second and others aren't.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you did not reload your code. Though you change and save your file, your script keeps running(did not restart and reload code). If you add autoreload the script will check your file whether has changed, and restart server when it detected you modified the code. **py-autoreload=N** means it will check your code ecah N second(s). Read more: https://serverfault.com/questions/411362/how-do-i-make-uwsgi-restart-when-a-python-script-is-modified/411363

Comment: Actually it is a bit more complex than that. When I changed my code, I explicitly killed the uwsgi instance that was running and launched it again, so the print should have been displayed. However, at some point I got tired of always killing/ relaunching uwsgi and added autoreload, and it started working after that. I know my changes were taken into account because if I put a python syntax error, the uwsgi instance I tried to launch throwed an error.

Comment: The document said that ***monitor python modules mtime to trigger reload (use only in development)***. Actually, it is more likely to DEBUG. Or said, it is debug module. @downstroy

Comment: And there is other description https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Snippets.html?highlight=py-autoreload#python-auto-reloading-development-only